# Trouble Parsing XML Into SQLite Database

Tags: android, sqlite

The application I am working on successfully parses data from an .xml file and stores it into a database. However, upon each application launch, the database will grow in size by the number of table rows the parsed data was stored into. For example, if the parsed data took three rows to store, then each subsequent application launch will increase the database to a size of (in terms of rows) six, then nine, then twelve, and so on and so forth.

What I would like is to prevent the table from increasing in size upon each application launch. I have tried resetting the database each time, but I'm not sure how to correctly go about this or if this is even the solution that I should be going for.

**I have a view to display the database in its entirety:**

```
public class QAView extends Activity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.qa_view);

        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvData);
        QADatabase entries = new QADatabase(this);
        try
        {
            entries.open();
            String data = entries.getAllData();
            tv.setText(data);
            entries.close();
        }
        catch(SQLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**I have parser code that processes data from an .xml file:**

```
    XmlResourceParser parser = getResources().getXml(R.xml.qa);

    try
    {
        while(parser.next() != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT)
        {
            if(parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.START_TAG)
            {
                continue;
            }

            String name = parser.getName();

            if(name.equals("question"))
            {
                question = readTextQuestion(parser);
            }
            else if(name.equals("options"))
            {
                readTextAnswers(parser);
            }
        }
    }
    catch(XmlPullParserException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

**I also have the corresponding database code:**

```
public class QADatabase
{
    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
    public static final String KEY_QUESTION = "question";
    public static final String KEY_ANSWER1 = "answer1";
    public static final String KEY_ANSWER2 = "answer2";
    public static final String KEY_ANSWER3 = "answer3";
    public static final String KEY_ANSWER4 = "answer4";
    public static final String KEY_ANSWER5 = "answer5";
    public static final String KEY_CORRECT = "correct";

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "QuestionAnswerDatabase";
    public static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "QuestionAnswerTable";
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;

    private DatabaseHelper ourHelper;
    private final Context ourContext;
    private SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase;

    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
    {
        private DatabaseHelper(Context context)
        {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase)
        {
            sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" +
                    KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
                    KEY_QUESTION + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                    KEY_ANSWER1 + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                    KEY_ANSWER2 + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                    KEY_ANSWER3 + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                    KEY_ANSWER4 + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                    KEY_ANSWER5 + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                    KEY_CORRECT + " TEXT NOT NULL);"
            );
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i2)
        {
            sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
            onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);
        }
    }

    public QADatabase(Context c)
    {
        ourContext = c;
    }

    public QADatabase open() throws SQLException
    {
        ourHelper = new DatabaseHelper(ourContext);
        ourDatabase = ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public void close()
    {
        ourHelper.close();
    }

    public void createEntry(String question, String answer1, String answer2, String answer3, String answer4, String answer5, String correct)
    {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(KEY_QUESTION, question);
        cv.put(KEY_ANSWER1, answer1);
        cv.put(KEY_ANSWER2, answer2);
        cv.put(KEY_ANSWER3, answer3);
        cv.put(KEY_ANSWER4, answer4);
        cv.put(KEY_ANSWER5, answer5);
        cv.put(KEY_CORRECT, correct);
        ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);
    }

    public String getAllData()
    {
        String[] columns = new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_QUESTION, KEY_ANSWER1, KEY_ANSWER2, KEY_ANSWER3, KEY_ANSWER4, KEY_ANSWER5, KEY_CORRECT};
        Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
        String result = "";

        while(c.moveToNext())
        {
            result = result + c.getString(0) + " " + c.getString(1) + " " + c.getString(2) + " " + c.getString(3) + " " + c.getString(4) + " " + c.getString(5) + " " + c.getString(6) + " " + c.getString(7) + "\n";
        }

        return result;
    }

    public String getQuestion(long l) throws SQLException
    {
        String[] columns = new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_QUESTION, KEY_ANSWER1, KEY_ANSWER2, KEY_ANSWER3, KEY_ANSWER4, KEY_ANSWER5, KEY_CORRECT};
        Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, KEY_ROWID + "=" + l, null, null, null, null);

        if(c != null)
        {
            // move the cursor to the first row
            c.moveToFirst();

            // look for ID "l" in the "Questions" column
            String question = c.getString(1);

            return question;
        }

        // otherwise, return null
        return null;
    }

    public String getAnswerChoice(long l, int answerChoiceNumber) throws SQLException
    {
        String[] columns = new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_QUESTION, KEY_ANSWER1, KEY_ANSWER2, KEY_ANSWER3, KEY_ANSWER4, KEY_ANSWER5, KEY_CORRECT};
        Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, KEY_ROWID + "=" + l, null, null, null, null);

        if(c != null)
        {
            // move the cursor to the first row
            c.moveToFirst();

            // look for ID "l" in the "Answers" column
            String correctAnswer = c.getString(answerChoiceNumber + 2); // need to offset by 2 for the KEY_ROWID and KEY_QUESTION columns

            return correctAnswer;
        }

        // otherwise, return null
        return null;
    }

    public Cursor getAllTitles()
    {
        return ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {
                KEY_ROWID, KEY_ANSWER1, KEY_ANSWER2, KEY_ANSWER3, KEY_ANSWER4, KEY_ANSWER5, KEY_CORRECT},
                null, null, null, null, null);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just assign a fixed primary ID (rowID) to each question, so doing it again and again will only gives you duplicate primary key constraint exception, your table wouldn't grow.